# jsPlumb connect loads into body

Tags: javascript, html, connection, jsplumb

I have a jsPlumb flowchart in a div named canvas. The anchors are loaded into this div, but the connection lines are loading into the body causing a really bad positioning and they're not moving with the canvas while scrolling

Here is the code of loading the connections.

```
for (i = 0; i < load_array.linkDataArray.length; i++) {
    var linkdata = load_array.linkDataArray[i];
    var anchors = [portToCoordinate(linkdata.fromPort), portToCoordinate(linkdata.toPort)];
    jsPlumb.connect({
        source: String(linkdata.from),
        target: String(linkdata.to),
        anchors: anchors
    });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and what I did was suspendDrawing the lines until I had the array with all the connections, so

1. Firs I suspend drawing connections

   ```
   jsPlumb.setSuspendDrawing(true);
   jsPlumb.setContainer("parentId"); //You can add a container in case you dont want the body to be the container
   ```
2. I load my data
3. Once I have all the data ( array with the connections)

   ```
   jsPlumb.setSuspendDrawing(false, true);
   jsPlumb.connect({source:--,target:--});
   ```

-- And for the scroll, I guess ir your connections are well draw you wont have this problem, anyway I use:

```
onResize(event) {
    jsPlumb.repaintEverything();
}
```

to repaint the lines everytime the windows is resized.